# Want to create a Dynamic entry table in another sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task to complete where I want to create a table using values from one sheet based on condition using VBA and ActiveX Button.

[This are table entries from which I need to pick values based on condition Cell(J, 62).values = "Not Compliant" or "Partially Compliant".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP9dq.jpg)

To understand it better, where ever in column J the value is "Not Compliant or Partially Compliant" for rows I want certain details to be included in a new sheet as dynamic entries. Below is the format of the new table that I would like to create. I have mentioned the column names that I want in the new table.

Column C | Serial No. (Values based number of entries) | Column L | Column M

The number of values may depend on the number of Not Compliant and Partially compliant numbers.

Can anyone help me getting a code for this. I am unable to write a logic for this condition.

Comment: Do you have sample data to work with and can you share the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 Sheets in your Workbook where the first sheet is your Table and the second sheet is the destination for the items where the data is not compliant:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunComplianceCheck()

Dim c As Range 'Each cell that the loop will look at to determine Compliance Status
Dim rng As Range 'The range of all the entries in the table
Dim totNC 'The total Non or Partially Compliance entries on the second tab

Sheet2.Activate 
Sheet2.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).ClearContents 'Clear all previous data

Sheet1.Activate
With Sheet1
    Set rng = .Range(Cells(2, 10), _
    Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("J:J")), 10)) 'Set the range of all the entries in the table
End With

For Each c In rng 'Loop through each entry
    If c.Value = "Not Compliant" Or c.Value = "Partially Compliant" Then 'If Not Compliant or Partially Complaint execute the below
        With Sheet2
            totNC = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1 'Get the first empty row on the second Sheet of Non or Partially Compliant data
            .Cells(totNC, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, -7).Value 'Get data in column C
            .Cells(totNC, 2).Value = c.Offset(0, -9).Value 'Get data in column A
            .Cells(totNC, 3).Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value 'Get data in column L
            .Cells(totNC, 4).Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value 'Get data in column M
        End With
    End If
Next c 'Next cell

Sheet2.Activate

End Sub
```

This sub will loop through each row of your data set and find the entries marked  Non-Compliant or Partially Compliant, then will grab the Question(s), Serial No., Finding / Gap Description, and Finding Rating data for each one (as requested) and place them in the second sheet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. However, I am getting Run time error '1004'. : Application defined or object defined error in Line number 7.